# MSSQL select JSON file with multirows and insert into table

Tags: json, sql-server

I read the docs of handling a JSON file [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/import-json-data-into-sql-server/). So far I am able to read the file and get a result:

```
QRY: SELECT *  FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'c:\ne.db', SINGLE_CLOB) as import
Result: {"res":{"number":"123", "info":"c-PM6900"},"_id":"aHMIeu6ZwB9lIBZk"} {"res":{"number":"456", "info":"a-PMs900"},"_id":"aHaIeu6ZwB9sIBZ1"}....
```

if I qry this, I only get the first row with the res nested:

```
Declare @JSON varchar(max)
SELECT @JSON=BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\ne.db', SINGLE_CLOB) import
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON)
```

[image: Result]

What I want to achieve, is to read every entry of the JSON file and insert **"res"** from the json query into a row of a table in the database containing columns **"number","info","id"**. If anyone could help me to finish this, I would appreciate.

The JSON file contains about 400000 lines and comes from a NodeJS script which uses nedb.

Here is the example file: [LINK](https://easyupload.io/c8n7v1)

Comment: A similar [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58801877/reading-file-containing-multiple-json-objects-using-ms-sql-server/58803622#58803622). The important part is that your JSON is not valid (it contains two or more root objects), but `OPENJSON()` successfully parses only the first of them. You can check this with a simple `SELECT ISJSON(@json)` call.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because from the comments on my answer, it appears that the code the OP has actually returns an error, not a dataset (as the image implies) and that there are other steps missing. The question suggests that the OP simply needs to consume the JSON data from  `OPENROWSET`, however, we now know that dataset is never returned. This feels like several questions need asking, starting with the syntax error the OP is getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON in the file is not a valid JSON, it contains multiple root elements or a single row for each JSON object. It's strange, but `OPENJSON()` reads only the first element in this JSON input without generating an error.

But you may try to transform the input JSON into a valid JSON array (`{...} {...}` into `[{}, {...}]`) and parse this JSON array with `OPENJSON()` and explicit schema. If the input file has a single row for each JSON object, you need to know the new line separator (it's usually `CHAR(10)`):

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(MAX) 

-- Read the file's content
-- SELECT @json = BulkColumn
-- FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\ne.db', SINGLE_CLOB) AS [Insert]

-- Only for test
SELECT @json = 
   N'{"res":{"number":"123", "info":"c-PM6900"},"_id":"aHMIeu6ZwB9lIBZk"}' +
   CHAR(10) +
   N'{"res":{"number":"456", "info":"a-PMs900"},"_id":"aHaIeu6ZwB9sIBZ1"}'

SELECT [number], [info], [_id]
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('[', REPLACE(@json, CONCAT('}', CHAR(10), '{'), '},{'), ']')) WITH (
   [number] varchar(3) '$.res.number',
   [info] varchar(10) '$.res.info',
   _id varchar(50) '$._id'
)
```

Result:

```
number info     _id
123    c-PM6900 aHMIeu6ZwB9lIBZk
456    a-PMs900 aHaIeu6ZwB9sIBZ1
```

Comment: Thank you @Zhorov, thats close! The only thing what will not work if you have the data contained in a file like you commented out.

Comment: {"res":{"number":"123", "info":"c-PM6900"},"_id":"aHMIeu6ZwB9lIBZk"}
{"res":{"number":"456", "info":"a-PMs900"},"_id":"aHaIeu6ZwB9sIBZ1"}

Comment: @Matthias, yes, the format of the file is important. Does it have one row for each JSON object?

Comment: Yes, the data is coming in line by line like: {"res":{"number":"123", "info":"c-PM6900"},"_id":"aHMIeu6ZwB9lIBZk"} and then next line and so on

Comment: @Matthias. just find the new line separator (probably `CHAR(10)`) and change `REPLACE(@json, '} {', '},{')` with `REPLACE(@json, '}' + CHAR(10) + '{', '},{')`. Another possible new line separator is `CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)`.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this. I did upload my "ne.db" example file in my question. Would you be able to take a look in it?

Comment: Saved my life. 336917 rows in 6sec instead of 1,5hours with the JavaScript. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a couple of calls to `OPENJSON` to achieve this, with a `WITH`:

```sql
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = N'{"res":{"number":"123", "info":"c-PM6900"},"_id":"aHMIeu6ZwB9lIBZk"} {"res":{"number":"456", "info":"a-PMs900"},"_id":"aHaIeu6ZwB9sIBZ1"}'

SELECT J._id,
       r.number,
       r.info
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON)
     WITH (_id varchar(30),
           res nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) J
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(J.res)
                 WITH(number int,
                     info varchar(10)) r;
```

Because the OP appears to think I am telling them to change their `DECLARE` and assignment statement... to confirm how you get the value into the `@JSON`, from the OP's own question:

> ```sql
> DECLARE @JSON varchar(max);
> SELECT @JSON=BulkColumn
> FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\ne.db', SINGLE_CLOB);
> ```

---

Final edit, is also appears that the OP's JSON is malformed, as I would expect a comma, or something, before the second `res` definition. Guessing we need to split it into rows as well, which means some string splitting:

```sql
SELECT J._id,
       r.number,
       r.info
FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(@JSON,N'}} {"res"',N'}}|{"res"'),'|') SS --I assume a pipe (|`) won't appear in the data
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(SS.[value])
                 WITH (_id varchar(30),
                       res nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) J
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(J.res)
                 WITH(number int,
                     info varchar(10)) r;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e7f208c6df758bf0ccb67bab222b901e)

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, but where would come N'{"res"':.....} from?

Comment: That's your data, @Matthias . I don't have access to your instance, so I put your example JSON in a variable.

Comment: So you want me to copy and paste 400000 lines of JSON data? 8D

Comment: No, you already show you're getting that from the file, @Matthias ... If you read your question, you demonstrator how you set the value of `@JSON`. This answer doesn't change that, so i don't understand your confusion.

Comment: Ah, so I need to select the BulkColumn first and use it in DECLARE? At the moment these are 2 diffrent querys in my MSSQL Studio, thats where my confusion came from.

Comment: Use your `DECLARE` and `SELECT` exactly as you have them, @Matthias .... The solution is the `OPENJSON`. Me assigning a literal to the variable doesn't change anything about how *you* assign it.

Comment: But I still have no idea how to vass the Result of: SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'c:\ne.db', SINGLE_CLOB) as import into the DECLARE.

Comment: ... @Matthias check your own question, you show what to do... `SELECT @JSON=BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\ne.db', SINGLE_CLOB) import`... Again, I don't understand your confusion... I'm not telling you to change that, so why do you want to? Are you saying that wasn't working? That isn't what your question says, and if it isn't working, then you should be asking a (separate) question about that, as how to use `OPENROWSET` and how to consume JSON are very different questions.

Comment: DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'c:\ne.db', SINGLE_CLOB) as import

SELECT J._id,
       r.number,
       r.info
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON)
     WITH (_id varchar(30),
           res nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) J
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(J.res)
                 WITH(number int,
                     info varchar(10)) r;

Comment: That will error, @Matthias .... Why are you changing the SQL that you had that was working...? *Again* I never told you to change that, the solution is the `OPENJSON` part... If you *must* use `DECLARE` and a `SELECT` in the same statement, the latter must be a subquery.

Comment: invalid syntaxI think we are talking about diffrent things. I need one SQLquery which grabs all the json data and put it in a sql table. Now, I do have two querys and I need to copy the result of the first query into the second query

Comment: *"I need to copy the result of the first query into the second query"* Huh? THat requirement isn't in your question at all. If you need to take a result set from one `SELECT` and use it in another you need to `INSERT` that data somewhere. Perhaps use an `INTO` to insert the data into a temporary table. None of those requirements are in your question though, so that is a completely different question.

Comment: *"invalid syntax"* if the SQL above in your question was giving you a syntax error as well, why didn't you tell us that? You image implies it's working as you show a result set. It seems you've missed out on telling us a lot of information here.

Comment: Ok, so what I understood now, is that my question: "What I want to achieve, is to read every entry of the JSON file and insert "res" from the json query into a row of a table in the database containing columns "number","info","id" is not possible in an easy way. It would be also ok, if it would be two querys, but I neet to have it done automatically. Maybe it woul be easier to try to parse it line by line in a javascript to make an easy insert qry. I was hoping MSSQL does have an easy way to import JSON.

Comment: *"I was hoping MSSQL does have an easy way to import JSON."* it does, `OPENJSON`, as I demonstrate.

Comment: Maybe, but it does not answer my question how to insert the data from the qry into the table.

Comment: Simply add an `INSERT INTO {Your Table} ({Columns})` before the `SELECT` @Matthias ; that's basic SQL. None of the above changes how fundament parts of SQL work; such as `SELECT`, `INSERT`, and `DECLARE`.

Comment: Sure, I have heard about INSERT. But your example gives me as result just the first row of 4000000 and my question was: "read every entry of the JSON file and insert "res""

Comment: It looks like your JSON is a little malformed, if I am honest, @Matthias . I would, for example, example a comma in the middle of `'...Zk"} {"res":...'`

Comment: I've made a final guess, @Matthias .

Comment: Thank you @Larnu, yes, it looks like I need to figure out to handle invalid JSON data, because the file comes from the customer as it is, and I don't want to change the file. I will hae to find out how to handle this apart from inserting etc.

Comment: @Matthias if it is space delimited (yuck, sorry), then the last solution should work, which turns it into Pipe Delimited and then runs against each JSON value.

Comment: Thank you again @Larnu, It turs out that parsing, splitting or whatever seems to be the chalange. Whe I use your fiddle, everything works fine, but when I use the file it only returns the first row again. But I am getting close to the problem now. I did also now uploaded the example ne.db file.